# Dunn test in R: comparison between levels of a single factor in a 2-factor experiment

Tags: r, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, dunn-test

For a 2-factor experiment, the TukeyHSD function in R (after a significant ANOVA) can calculate P values for the differences between levels of a single factor (basically, comparisons between the marginal means) as well as the interaction between factors. For example:

$FactorA

|  | diff | lwr | upr | p adj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2-A1 | 4.8977778 | 4.09780472 | 5.6977508 | 0.0000000 |
| A3-A1 | 5.7600000 | 4.96002694 | 6.5599731 | 0.0000000 |

$FactorB

|  | diff | lwr | upr | p adj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B2-B1 | -5.863333 | -6.490502 | -5.2361647 | 0.0000000 |
| B3-B1 | -6.748333 | -7.375502 | -6.1211647 | 0.0000000 |

$ FactorA:FactorB

|  | diff | lwr | upr | p adj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2:B1-A1:B1 | 5.320000e+00 | 3.50896459 | 7.13103541 | 0.0000000 |
| A3:B1-A1:B1 | 9.926667e+00 | 8.11563125 | 11.73770208 | 0.0000000 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

But the nonparametric Dunn test (after a significant Scheirer–Ray–Hare test) doesn't seem to be able to do this. It can only do the comparison for the factor interaction (i.e. $ FactorA:FactorB), or as far as I know how to do it.

Is there a way I can do the Dunn test for each individual factor?